# Picking images and videos on Android on 2.1 using ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, camera, android-intent, image-gallery

I'm working on an app that needs to have the user select an image or video.  On pre-2.1 devices, using ACTION_GET_CONTENT seems to work fine with multiple MIME types:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("video/*, image/*")
```

However, on a Droid running 2.1, this gives a "There are no items in your collection".  Using the same code with either "video/*" or "image/*" gives the desired result.  Is there a way to get my 2.1 device to allow the user to select both types of content within a single Intent?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the request into a function and then calling the function with `onClick()`.

```
public void openGalleryImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image "),
            SELECT_IMAGE);
}

public void openGalleryVideo(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select vVideo "), 
            SELECT_VIDEO);
}
```